# Knockout "with" binding removing child elements?

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

Another question dealing with knockout...

I have the following ViewModel I created (simplified):

```
var SearchViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    //Properties
    self.resultData = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedItem = ko.observable();

    //Methods
    self.SearchByName = function (name) {
        var url = "services/User/SearchByName/" + escape(name),
        callback = function (data) { $.each(data, function (i, e) { self.resultData.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(e)); }); self.selectedItem = self.resultData()[0]; };

    $.getJSON(url, callback);
    };

    self.UpdateSelection = function (item) {
        self.selectedItem = item;
    };
};
```

With this model I use the following code to bind it to the UI:

```
var vm = new SearchViewModel();

vm.SearchByName("Doe");

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

The results are applied to the following:

```
<div class="search-results" data-bind="foreach: resultData">
    <div class="search-result" data-bind="click: $parent.UpdateSelection">
        <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: Id"/>
        <div>
            <h4 data-bind="text: Name"></h4>
        </div>

        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6">
                <label class="font-italic">Username: </label>
                <span data-bind="text: Username"></span></div>
            <div class="span6">
                <label class="font-italic">Created: </label>
                <span data-bind="text: Created"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

All of this works fine, but when one of the results are clicked, I want a new jQuery UI dialog box to open allowing the user to edit some fields.  I attempt to use the following to accomplish this:

```
<div id="edit-user-form" title="Edit User" data-bind="with: selectedItem">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span5">
            <label>Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: LastName" />
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <label>First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: FirstName" />
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
        <label>Middle Name:</label>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: MiddleName" />
    </div>
</div>
```

but when I look at the form, all the html  child to the `edit-user-form` is wiped out.  I read that issues could be caused by the jQuery UI dialog and how it moves the elements around, but without having the dialog box open and examining the html, it still is blanked out.

Why is this occurring?  I thought it might be because of the `with` binding, but I thought it was the purpose of it.

Using Knockout v2.3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use template binding instead of using selected item

example for template binding is here

view model:

```
viewModel.selectedArticle = ko.observable();
viewModel.templateToUse = function(item) {
return item === this.selectedArticle() ? ‘edit’ : this.selectedView();
}.bind(viewModel);
```

html:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: templateToUse, foreach: articles }"></div>
```

Link:    http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Ujr4z/

hope this may help you

Comment: This looks like it would work with the  `search-result` part, but how does this help me with binding the clicked item to my other dialog box?

Comment: It seems some of my other code interfered with knockout's ability to react to changes in the observable object.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
if
```

and

```
ifnot
```

bindings to switch between the two html scripts... !!!... that's what i do as an alternative for templates

Comment: Why are you adding another answer instead of editing your previous one?

Comment: this is another way of knockout binding instead of using template